# MUI Box/Grid Layout exceeding window height

Tags: html, css, layout, material-ui

I'm having a hard time understanding how to keep the contents of a table inside of a box/grid/container with MUI (or any flex type of thing).

The goal is a simple screen with a toolbar and a table below that scrolls and is height responsive (i.e. no need for a main vertical scroll - everything should be scrollable within the components).  However the table goes beyond the bottom of the grid/window which subsequently doesn't enable the scroll on the bottom grid item.

I know I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something here.  Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

```
        <Grid
          container
          spacing={1}
          direction="column"
          justifyContent="flex-start"
          alignItems="flex-start"
          
          >
          <Grid item
          sx={{width: '100%'}}
          >
            <ThemeProvider theme={appbartheme}>
              <MainAppBar
                setScreenSelected={setScreenSelected}
              />
            </ThemeProvider>

          </Grid>
          <Grid
            item
            sx={{ overflowY: 'scroll', width: '100%' }}
          >
            <CPCContainer
              screenSelected={CPCGridSchemas[0]}
            />

          </Grid>


        </Grid>
```

Additionally I have this to suppress the main vertical scroll

```
html{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```